# How does fork and pipe work in a unix process system?

Tags: unix, pipe, fork

I'm trying to study for an exam and I'm just not able to figure out a simple fork program.

I have this piece of code and have to add code to it In order for the parent process to send through a PIPE the value `n` to the child. The child should double the value, not print anything and return it to the parent.

Then the parent should print it on the screen.

```
int main() {
int n=1;
if(fork() == 0) {
}
printf(“%d\n”, n);
return 1;
}
```

I don't really know how PIPEs work and how to use them. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pid_t cp;
int fi[2],st;
int n;
if(pipe(fi)==-1) {perror("pipe error");exit(0);}
if((cp=fork())==-1) {perror("fork"); exit(0);}
else if(cp==0)
 {
        sleep(2);
       close(fi[1]);
      read(fi[0],&n,2);
       n*=2;
        close(fi[0]);
        exit(n);
  }
  else
   {
        close(fi[0]);
         write(fi[1],n,2);
        close(fi[1]);
        waitpid(cp,&st,0);
          printf("%d",st);
          exit(0);
  }}
```

The working of pipes is very simple. A PIPE contains two ends, 1 for reading and another for writing. You have to close the appropriate end while reading or writing. After that you use it as a regular file with read() and write() functions.
 Forgive me for my formatting, I'm typing on a mobile.