# How does subprocess capture the output of a process with a pipe?

Tags: python, subprocess

What exactly does subprocess do to capture the output of the of the thing being run?

- Is it using some OS hook to direct the output into a shared ram space?
- Does it direct the process to write to a file on disk that it then reads? Where is the file?
- Network Socket?
- Does it do something else?

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Windows 10

Python 3.7

Comment: It probably depends on the Python implementation and/or the operating system involved. For example, `subprocess.py` imports a C module `_winapi` for Windows and `_posixsubprocess` for POSIX operating systems.

Comment: For UNIX, see the `mkfifo` call, creating a pair of file descriptors such that content written to one can be read from the other. This is how shell process substitution works too.

Comment: That said, questions need to be about a specific technical problem you actually face to be on topic; curiosity doesn't count. Requiring details to be nailed down avoids ambiguity, such as the case here where you haven't specified which operating system the question applies to.

Comment: (mkfifo is _also_ the underlying mechanism behind shell pipes; when you run `foo | bar`, it's an anonymous FIFO connected to the stdout of foo and the stdin of bar)

Comment: Arguably this question is duplicative of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379294/how-does-fork-and-pipe-work-in-a-unix-process-system, insofar as it's asking about UNIX.

Comment: Pair point on the OS. Unfortunately it's not curiosity but unfortunately I can't go into too much detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could check its [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/subprocess.py), it's just a fancy wrapper around [Create Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa), for windows which accepts input and output and error buffers, which are typically buffers wrapped as python TextIO buffer. (think of it like StringIO or BytesIO buffers)

on linux since there is no CreateProcess function, this is changed to a fork then exec after rewiring the standard input and output buffers, which you can check [its source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_posixsubprocess.c)

Comment: Linux _does_ have a spawn family -- fork+exec isn't the only choice, though I'd argue that from a flexibility perspective it's the _best_ choice; the massive complexity in CreateProcess is necessary on account of the inability to shift the work into application-provided code run between the fork and the exec. Splitting these up and letting the OS do less work was one of the early innovations UNIX doesn't get enough credit for.